# jquery $(window).height() and $(document).height() return the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, height

I need my background image to be below my menu div. So instead of applying the background to the body element I put in another bg div that contains my body div and set the width to 100%.(My body div has a specified width) I set the background inside the bg div.

I tested it and I got half a background picture because the document was not long enough. So I'm attempting to make a javascript fix for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
.....
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDocumentSize() {
    alert($(window).height());
    alert($(document).height());
    if ($(window).height()>$(document).height()) {
        var height = $(window).height()-$(document).height();
        document.getElementById('bg').style.height=height+"px"
        }
    }
.....
</script>
.....
<body onload="setDocumentSize()">
<div class="menu">
.....
</div>
<div class="bg">
    <div class="body">
    .....(background in this div) 
    </div>
</div>
```

Now both alerts pop up with the viewport height. Therefore nothing happens.

I'm using Firefox 16.0.2

Here is a link to the actual page http://servapps.dyndns-work.com/abstract/

Comment: When your doc is not beyond the window (no scrollbar) They show the same. When you minimize your window to the point the scrollbar pops up and refresh your page, you may get the clue .. :-)

Comment: why not just use a min-height of the image height for the background div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in CSS. You need to make sure that all containing elements are at least the height of the page (`height: 100%`). This includes both the `html` and `body` elements.

This code should work with your website:

```
html, body, #bg {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One more reason this could fail is when the doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) is missing. Adding this fixes the `$(window).height()` to return proper viewport height.

Comment: Thanks! I was literally going crazy over this!

I wonder why is it so? Does anybody have a clue?